# JUnit error in Kotlin : UninitializedException - lateinit variable has not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, dagger

I am writing JUnit test for Kotlin project. I am also using Dagger and AAPT in my project so there are Application class dependencies attached with the ViewModel classes as per below:

Application class :

```
class BaseApplication : Application() {
private lateinit var component: AppComponent

companion object {
    lateinit var instance: BaseApplication
        private set
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    instance = this
    component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .databaseModule(DatabaseModule(this))
        .connectivityModule(ConnectivityModule(this)).build()
    }
}
```

ViewModel :

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {
@Inject
lateinit var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager
private val injector: AppComponent = DaggerAppComponent
    .builder()
    .networkModule(NetworkModule)
    .databaseModule(DatabaseModule(BaseApplication.instance))
    .connectivityModule(ConnectivityModule(BaseApplication.instance))
    .build()

init {
    inject()
}

private fun inject() {
    when (this) {
        is ChildListViewModel -> injector.inject(this)
    }
}

fun isNetworkConnected(): Boolean {
    return if (connectivityManager is ConnectivityManager) {
        val networkInfo: NetworkInfo? =           connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        networkInfo?.isConnected ?: false
       } else false
    }
  }
```

In my testclass when I am trying to initialise the ViewModel class it is throwing error :

> UninitializedException lateinit var has not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to initialize BaseViewModel coz I see this class as abstract in the code you have shown ? ViewModel are lifecycle aware and they should be instantiated from within the activity itself.